# Right way to minify Angular2 files

Tags: angular, gulp

I've created webpack build from A2. It's a big file with all my components and this file works properly(if I include this file instead minified version) and all components/views/templates works as expected.
But I want to uglify this file with gulp, and after minification some functionality is lost or won't work properly, for example - some html templates won't be rendered.
I want to know - what I've missed or maybe my gulpfile isn't setup properly?
Here is:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
        aa_rename = require('gulp-rename'),
        aa_uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
        aa_sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('aa-production', function() {
    return gulp.src([
        'AppProductionLive/angular2live.js',
    ])
        .pipe(aa_sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(aa_rename('a2uglify.js'))
        .pipe(aa_uglify())
        .pipe(aa_sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('AppProductionLive'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['aa-production'], function() {});
```

Seems, something is lost when code being minified.
And console didn't render any error.

Comment: see official doc about minification / uglify() https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html#!#tree-shaking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With webpack you can use `UglifyJsPlugin` to uglify the code. check uglify  js's more config options on [official usage documentation](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#usage)

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/UglifyJsPlugin');

plugins: [
  // your other webpack plugin 

  new UglifyJsPlugin({
    beautify: false, //prod
    mangle: {
      screw_ie8: true,
      keep_fnames: true
    }, //prod
    compress: {
      screw_ie8: true
    }, //prod
    comments: false //prod
  })
]
```